# When/how does Python use PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pythonpath, sys.path

I'm having some trouble understanding how Python uses the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. According to the documentation, the import search path (`sys.path`) is "Initialized from the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, plus an installation-dependent default."

In a Windows command box, I started Python (v.2.7.6) and printed the value of `sys.path`. I got a list of pathnames, the "installation-dependent default."

Then I quit Python, set `PYTHONPATH` to `.;./lib;`, restarted Python, and printed `os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].` I got `.;./lib;` as expected. Then I printed `sys.path`. I think it should have been the installation-dependent default with `.;./lib;` added to the start or the end. Instead it was the installation-dependent default alone, as if `PYTHONPATH` were empty. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It always uses `PYTHONPATH`. What happened is probably that you quit python, but didn't quit your console/command shell. For that shell, the environment that was set when the shell was started still applies, and hence, there's no `PYTHONPATH` set.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't quit the shell because I didn't want to change PYTHONPATH permanently! I thought that if Python updated the value of PYTHONPATH it would have to update the value of sys.path as well -- where does sys.path come from, after all? But I'll settle for understanding what happened without understanding why.